# Click-once deployment exception

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I am trying to deploy simple winforms application using SQL CE. Here is what I have done

1. Create a new **Windows Forms application**.
2. Added  Data Source  (`MyDatabase.mdf`) to project.
3. Copied all the DLL as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983340%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
4. Selected **MyDatabase.mdf** file in Solution Explorer and changed its properties:
   "Build Action" property is set as "Content".
   The "Copy to Output Directory" property is set as "Copy if newer".
5. Added **System.Data.Sqlserver.ce** to the references folder (Copy to Local is True)
6. Project Property -> Publish tab -> In "Application Files" Button
   the database file is in the list, and  its “Publish Status” is set as “Data File (Auto)” and “Download Group” is set as “(Required)”.
7. In my Form Button Click I added

   ```
     private void LoadConnection()
     {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyDatabase.mdf");
       try
       {

           con.Open();
           MessageBox.Show("Connection was succesfull");
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ex.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
8. Publish using Publish wizard and setup is created.

When I run this setup  on my machine it works perfect  (I have already installed MS SQL server 2008 on my machine).But on a machine without SQL Server it gives error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

What else do I need to add to the other machine.

P.S I am using .Net framework 4